# Serialise serialize() parameters in AUI script

Tags: javascript, liferay-aui

In Jquery, we can do something like this.

```
    submithFormAjax : function (){
    var str = $("#searchform").serialize();
    var urlStr  =   document.getElementById('searchform').action;
        $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        data:str,
        url:urlStr
        ,
          success: function(){
        
         }
        });
        }
```

What is the equivalent way to do this in AUI script?

Many thanks